# Laravel - remove single record from table without primary key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table without `'primary ID'`, ex.

```
+---------+----------+------------+------------+  
| user_id | point_id | created_at | updated_at |  
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

And I have records:

```
1 ..| 200 | (date) | (date)  
14 | 300 | (date) | (date)  
1 ..| 200 | (date) | (date)
```

Now I want delete only one record to get:

```
1 ..| 200 | (date) | (date)  
14 | 300 | (date) | (date)  
I tryied:  

UserPoint::where( 'point_id', $reqId )->where( 'user_id', $userId )->first()->delete();
```

But it always remove all record with this params ... Anyone can help?
**EDIT:** My UserPoint model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserPoint extends Model {

    protected $table = 'point_user';

    public function scopeUsed($query){
        return $query->where('amount', '<', 0);
    }

    public function scopeEarned($query){
        return $query->where('amount', '>', 0);
    }

    public function about(){
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Point', 'id', 'point_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: Just tested similar query, it works as expected. Double check everything, this query should delete just one row.

Comment: can you show us your model UserPoint

Comment: @Carlos I edited first post.

Comment: @Vertisan i recommend you add a primary key, i search around and many similar post suggest the same, haven't found a way around this yet

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to achieve this deletion is somewhat wrong as it does not follow the rules of data integrity . Deleting a child table in your case would impose what we call an orphaned table.

However the correct way of deleting that record would be to first associate this table to its parent related table in this case as below:

```
Class User extends Model { 

  public function points() {

    return $this->hasMany(UserPoint::class)

  }
}
```

then in your UserPoint Class or Model you then need to map your relation.

```
class UserPoint extends Model {

protected $table = 'point_user';
// I have added this part
public function users() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class)
}

public function scopeUsed($query){
    return $query->where('amount', '<', 0);
}

public function scopeEarned($query){
    return $query->where('amount', '>', 0);
}

public function about(){
    return $this->hasOne('\App\Point', 'id', 'point_id');
}
```

}

This way you when deleting the Model  or Item you can simply do the below:
// Inject your User in the constructor or function - lets say you names it User $user

```
$user->points->delete();
```

I suggest you also look at Eloquent's association and sync methods when working with relations this way you always know that the related Models are on sync and there re no orphaned children in the database which in Enterprise Design is a huge problem as accuracy and Data intergrity is everything .